# Add a method to a Genexus's User Control made in Android

Tags: android, genexus, genexus-sd

I' am trying to develop a User Component for Genexus X EV 3 for Smart Devices. It's about a personalized webview, I have used it in a project, it works but only using the predefined methods that bring Genexus, I can't figure out how to call a method of the .java file, from the Genexus project. In the .control file I added the method definition:

```
<Methods>
        <Method>          
          <Name>UCgoBack</Name>
               <ReturnType />
               <Parameters>
               </Parameters>
               <Signature>UCgoBack()</Signature>
        </Method>
</Methods>
```

Genexus recognizes the user Control, I can see the method in the IntelliSense, but when I call it, is not executed. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2):

In your User Control's Android class, you need to implement the `runMethod` method, that gets called by GeneXus when there is a method call.

This is the method's signature:

```
public void runMethod(String name, List<Object> parameters)
```

The `name` is the method name as defined in your `.control` file. The `parameters` list should be empty in your case (because your method has no parameters).

As an example, the Horizontal Grid control has two methods, you can find the implementation in the Flexible Client (search for `GxMagazineViewer.java`)

Comment: I added the method to the class and that still doesn't work. It seems that genexus does not recognises that method. Should I need to implement another interface than "IGxEdit", in the two examples I have "IGxControlRuntime" is implemented but I dont have the documentation of that interface.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, IGxControlRuntime interface must be implemented:

```
@Override
public void setProperty(String name, Object value) {
}

@Override
public Object getProperty(String name) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public void runMethod(String methodName, List<Object> parameters) {
    if (methodName.toLowerCase().startsWith("methodname")){
        methodname();
    }
}
```

and those methods must be implemented. Thank you very much Marcos for guiding me.